# Unity Facebook create object request returns 403

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app in Unity, and we're using distribution of items on Facebook for social features. We completely (and successfully) integrated during Unity 4.x with Facebook's Unity SDK v6 and using api v2.3. iOS has forced our hand and we are now upgrading everything to modern: to Unity 5, Facebook Unity 7, and API 2.5. Most of the transition has been completed, but one particular Facebook feature remains broken on Android specifically: a create object call to send to inviteable friends. Everything works on iOS and in the editor. Here's the call that breaks:

```
var formDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"title", "AskForLife"},
    {"type", "woogy_gemjunction:life"},
    {"app_id", FB.AppId.ToString()}
};
var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "object", Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(formDict) } };
FB.API("/me/objects/woogy_gemjunction:life", HttpMethod.POST, CreateFBLifeCallback, formData);
```

The callback is pretty simple. We are getting "Error during object create call!  403: Forbidden" whenever the above code is run.

```
public void CreateFBLifeCallback(IGraphResult result)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Error during object create call! " + result.Error);
    }
    else if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        <<this code is never reached>>
    }
}
```

This works properly on other platforms, which would seem to suggest that the request is not badly formatted, and we can successfully login and review and respond to received messages in Android, so I don't think this is an access token issue. The "Life" graph object is extremely simple, inheriting from Object and adding no extra properties: og:type and og:title are the only required fields, but those are both provided in the request. Hints or suspicions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you intercept the request on the device where you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has never become fully clear, but the issue appears to have been in our test accounts and devices. I was manually logging into a Facebook test account that may not have granted the proper permissions to the app. This code works perfectly under any normal conditions.